# Mono response from a method which returns void

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a service method which does not result anything, but can return an HttpException.
example

```
class Service{
public void myService() throws HttpException{
//do something
}
}
```

My calling class has a method which is supposed to return a Mono. This method calls myService().

```
class Caller{
@Autowire
Service service;

public Mono<Response> callMyService(){

return Mono.just("abc")
           .doOnSuccess(service.myService())
           .thenReturn(new Response()); //this should return Mono<Response>

}

}
```

My question, is how can I write callMyService() in a good way? Mono.just("abc") doesn't seem right implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Mono<Void>` for this purpose. This mono will not forward any data, it will only signal error or completion.
You can create it using [then()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then--)

Also, remember that `doOnSuccess()` is side effect. You should not use it for data processing, maybe use `map()` or `flatMap()`. For you case, maybe you can use `Mono.fromCallable(()->service.myService())`, but that may not be correct depending on what service actually does.